# Where to customise UINavigationController back button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am probably missing the obvious here, I am in a viewController that has been pushed onto a `UINavigationController` stack when the user selects a button on the "Main" screen.

[image]

What I am trying to do is get to a point where I can access the `UIBarButtonItem` for the back button (Shown on the image as "Main") and call `setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` to customize the button.

What I am confused about is do I need to do this from each `UIViewController` that is pushed on, or is it something that I need to do just once on the `UINavigationController` itself?

I thought I might be able to access what I wanted from the pushed controller using:

```
UINavigationItem *navItem = [self navigationItem];
```

but think I am getting mixed up with the way things are setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one that can customize the back button is the controller that disappears, say, you have controller A that pushes into controller B. The back button that you see on controller B is A's back button.

If you want to customize ALL buttons in your app, you could subclass `UINavigationController`, make sure you use it and not a regular `UINavigationController` and on the `pushViewController:animated` method you could do this:

```
controller.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = ...; // Your custom back button
[super pushViewController...];
```

**EDIT**
You cannot access the default back button, you can only create a new one to replace it.

Comment: Ah I see, the reason I was getting lost was that I was looking for ways to change the existing back button. I managed to change the text and thats what was leading me on the wrong path, much appreciated.